# If I buy a new Acer Aspire with New Microsoft Windows 7 Starter pre-installed w/CoA, can I upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7

If I buy new Acer Aspire w/New Microsoft Windows 7 Sarter pre-installed w/CoA, can I upgrade to Windows 10?

Comment: [this site](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-10-upgrade-paths) says you can upgrade Windows 7 starter to Windows 10 home